# Assign an expression to a property inside the expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, expression

Is there a way to assign the 'result' of a selector expression to the property of another selector inside an expression tree?

To clarify: I'd like to transform a result set retrieved from the database into a data transfer object using a selector expression. My example would normally look like this:

```
Expression<Func<Parent, ParentDto>> selector = parent =>
new ParentDto {
    Children = parent.Children.Select(x => new ChildDto())...
```

This however doesn't work with *Linq To Entities* as `Children` (property on entity `Parent`) is just an `IEnumerable<T>` **without initializer**. For this case, I have a *static expression accessor* (`public static Expression<Func<Parent, ICollection<Child>>> ChildrenAccessor = f => f.InternalChildrenStorage`) which returns the internal collection (`ICollection<T>`). Now I need to:

1. Create a dto mapping expression for the child entities
2. Create a dto mapping expression for the parent entity (parent entity)
3. Replace the parameters of my static accessor with the ones from the child entities mapping expression
4. Combine the parent mapping expression with the child entities mapping expression

In the end, it should (pseudo) be like this:

```
Expression<Func<Parent, ParentDto>> selector = parent =>
    new ParentDto {
        Children = parent.InternalChildrenStorage.Select(x => new ChildDto())...
```

Here's what I got (realworld code):

```
// Parent = SetupGroup
// Child  = SetupMap

Expression<Func<ICollection<SetupMap>, IEnumerable<SetupMapDto>>> transformMapsToDto =
        maps => maps.Select(x => new SetupMapDto
        {
            Camera = new SetupMapCameraDto
            {
                Id = x.Camera.Id,
                FriendlyName = x.Camera.FriendlyName
            },
            Display = new SetupMapDisplayDto
            {
                Id = x.Display.Id,
                FriendlyName = x.Display.FriendlyName
            }
        }).Where(x => x.Camera != null);
var mapsSelector = SetupGroup.SetupMapsAccessor.Combine(transformMapsToDto);
    Expression<Func<SetupGroup, SetupGroupReportDto>> transformGroupsToDto = @group 
        => new SetupGroupReportDto {
            GroupText   = @group.GroupText,
            GroupNumber = @group.GroupNumber
        };

Expression<Func<SetupGroupReportDto, IEnumerable<SetupMapDto>>> dtoMapsSelector = dto => dto.SetupMaps;
var parameterExpression = (ParameterExpression) (((MemberExpression) (dtoMapsSelector.Body)).Expression);
var assignment = Expression.Lambda<Action<SetupGroupReportDto>>(Expression.Assign(dtoMapsSelector.Body, mapsSelector.Body),
                    parameterExpression);

var resultDtoBlock      = Expression.Block(transformGroupsToDto, assignment);

var selectorParameter   = Expression.Parameter(typeof (SetupGroup));
var dtoSelector         = Expression.Lambda<Func<SetupGroup, SetupGroupReportDto>>(resultDtoBlock, selectorParameter);

var results = _setupGroupRepository.GetAll(dtoSelector);
```

This doesn't seem to work however as the second part of the block expression (the assignment) doesn't get combined with the `transformGroupsToDto` expression. Did I misunderstand the purpose of `Expression.Block`?